# How to mock toDate Timestap method in Jest and NestJS

Tags: node.js, firebase, unit-testing, jestjs, nestjs

I am trying to test (with jest) one controller which use firebase to get users data as you can
see in the next example

```
    const queryPersonalInfo = (
      await firebase
        .firestore()
        .collection('users')
        .doc(user)
        .get()
    ).data();


    const strokeInfo: StrokeInfo = {
      birthDay: queryPersonalInfo.birthday.toDate(),
      height: queryPersonalInfo.height,
      weight: queryPersonalInfo.weight,
      hypertensive: queryPersonalInfo.hypertensive,
      smoker: queryPersonalInfo.smoker,
      fa: lastUserRecord.hasAnomaly,
    };

    return this.strokeRiskService.calculateStrokeRisk(strokeInfo);
  }
}
```

I mocked the `firebase-admin` library as is shown

```
  initializeApp: jest.fn(),
  firestore: () => ({
    collection: jest.fn(collectionName => ({
      doc: jest.fn(docName => ({
        get: jest.fn(() => ({
          data: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({
            birhtday: "2020-05-05T10:53:47.414Z",
            height: 180,
            weight: 80,
            hypertensive: true,
            smoker: true,
            fa: true,
            diabetic: false,
          }),
        })),
      })),
    })),
  }),  
}));
```

But the test fails because doesn't recognize toDate() method.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'toDate' of undefined

      48 |     console.log(queryPersonalInfo);
      49 |     const strokeInfo: StrokeInfo = {
    > 50 |       birthDay: queryPersonalInfo.birthday.toDate(),
         |                                            ^
      51 |       height: queryPersonalInfo.height,
      52 |       weight: queryPersonalInfo.weight,
      53 |       hypertensive: queryPersonalInfo.hypertensive,

      at StrokeRiskController.getStrokeRisk (stroke-risk/stroke-risk.controller.ts:50:44)
```

If I remove `toDate()` method the test works.
 Does anyone know what is going on?

Comment: You have a typo in `birhtday`.

Answer (score 1):

Your mock data needs to have the `birthday` property being an object with a `toDate` method. It can look something like this:

```js
  initializeApp: jest.fn(),
  firestore: () => ({
    collection: jest.fn(collectionName => ({
      doc: jest.fn(docName => ({
        get: jest.fn(() => ({
          data: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({
            birthday: {
              toDate: () => "2020-05-05T10:53:47.414Z",
            },
            height: 180,
            weight: 80,
            hypertensive: true,
            smoker: true,
            fa: true,
            diabetic: false,
          }),
        })),
      })),
    })),
  }),  
}));
```

This will make sure that `queryPersonalInfo.birthday.toDate()` is a callable method that returns what you expect it to.